# How do I prevent vs2010 of changing spaces into tabs in the entire document?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabs, spaces, autoformatting

In

> Tools>Options>Text Editor>All Languages>Tabs

I have "Keep tabs" selected. I work in a branch of a project and I'd like to keep the pending changes as minimal as possible. Especially in VB files, whenever I add or modify a few lines and save, it sometimes sets all the spaces *(of all the indentations)* to tabs, resulting in too many changes.

I want VS2010 to only change the indentations of the lines I modified or added into tabs, the other indentations should remain spaces or tabs. How do I do this?

Comment: You are not going to get a workaround for this here.  Bite the bullet and take a one-time change-the-world commit.  Get rid of all the tabs in every file.  It's Friday, good day for that.

Comment: I did the trick though, by disabling "pretty listing" in Tools>Options>Text Editor>Basic>VB Specific. That disabled many other autoformatting features that actualy were usefull, but it doesn't realy matter since the changes I've made are few.